# C++ - One Function Declaration, Multiple definitions, And it still works?

Tags: c++, function-definition

OK, I have 3 files, a header, a source for said header, and a main. In the header file, I define a class with a function. In the source file, I define the function. But, in the Main file, I *redefine* the function, and then make an instance of the class in the main function and call the function. This compiles just fine - no warning whatsoever. And the output is scary to say the least.

Header: testme.h

```
#ifndef testme_h_
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class wtf {
public:
  string getStr();
};

#endif
```

Source: testme.cpp

```
#include "testme.h"

string wtf::getStr() {
  return "Hello World!";
};
```

Main: main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "testme.h"

string wtf::getStr()
{
  return "God is Dead.";
}

int main()
{
  wtf f;
  cout << f.getStr() << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
God is Dead.
```

Why does this work? Why isn't there an error regarding multiple definitions? Why does the souce file's definition just get ignored? Why no warnings?

**Partial Answer**
When this is recompiled as "g++ main.cpp testme.cpp -o sanity.o" it does, in fact, produce a linker error.

What gets me, however is that this little case I wrote mirrors an issue I have in a larger program that has a function defined in a library, and yet we redefine a function in another "test suite" program in much the same way. Why is this so? What about it being in a library allows it to override the ODR?

Comment: Undefined Behaviour you are breaking the One Definition Rule. See __One Definition Rule__ in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition

Comment: That's what I thought! But is that really something my compiler wouldn't catch? Not even a warning?

Comment: No the compiler only sees each .cpp file as a separate compilation unit.  The linker _may_ complain or it may just pick one and throw the other away. UB is UB as they say.

Comment: Not necessarily -- what are your compiler/linker commands?  Do you link with testme.o?

Comment: It's only very basic. 

g++ main.cpp -o wtf.o

Comment: `string wtf::getStr() { return "Hello World!" };` is a prototype and `string wtf::getStr() { return "God is Dead."; }` is the definition of that prototype, notice the `;` after the curly bracket... your compiler includes `#include "testme.h"` as if you write that code before `int main()
{...}`

Comment: @UtMan88 With that command, the compiler never sees `testme.o`, so it doesn't know that there's another definition.

Comment: That's from me not typing straight (flabbergasted by this issue). Fixed it, still produces the same output. (Main question fixed)

Comment: So, I added in testme.cpp to the compile options, and, yes, the multiple definition linker error comes up.

What gets me, however is that this littl case I wrote mirrors an issue i have in a larger program that has a function defined in a library, and yet we redefine a function in another "test suite" program in much the same way...

Comment: Part of the justification for undefined behavior is that some rules are hard to enforce.  If a rule is easy to enforce, the committee generally requires an error, or a diagnostic of some kind.  But if the rule is hard to enforce, then the committee declares that violating the rule will be undefined.

A compiler could, potentially, figure out this problem in some cases; especially if the linker and compiler are the same program.  But there are cases (separate compilation) where the compiler won't necessarily ever have enough information to be able to enforce the one definition rule.

Comment: If you don't link testme.o then it means testme.cpp is not part of your program

Comment: The first C++ textbook I read included a story about Sun developers who had created a `mktemp` function without realizing it conflicted with a system function with a very different purpose ( https://www.gnu.org/software/autogen/mktemp.html ).  They got different behavior depending on which order the linker processed their files, and that order changed between compilations.  The story was a great sales pitch for namespaces.

Comment: The build command in the question now would create an executable called "sanity.o"  ; hopefully that is not actually what you are doing

Comment: Why this is scary to you? In most situation this will never happened until you intentionally do this. There are ways even to change function at runtime and nobody is getting white hair about it.

Comment: Well, just to clarify, this was a sample program i wrote to mock up the problem in a much, much larger application. I just didn't know it was going around the ODR so easily, and still don't understand how it does it in a library.

Comment: Libraries are not covered by the standard, so they can break any rules they want. Historically, libraries provide definitions for things that are missing. In your case, nothing was missing, so the library was not used.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does this work? Why isn't there an error regarding multiple definitions? Why does the souce file's definition just get ignored? Why no warnings?
>
> Partial Answer When this is recompiled as "g++ main.cpp testme.cpp -o sanity.o" it does, in fact, produce a linker error.

In *Design and Evolution of C++*, Stroustrup says that when designing a feature he would occasionally have the choice between (1) a convoluted rule that the compiler would be able to enforce with warnings and error messages, or (2) a simple rule that the compiler may not be able to enforce in all cases.  He tried to choose simple rules, and he hoped that compilers would eventually be able to enforce/detect errors.  There are several parts of C and C++ that, effectively, show what the state of the art was in the 1970s, 1980s, 1990s, etc. (e.g., `inline`, `register`, `volatile`).  There could have been more.

Roughly speaking, this trade off is the source of undefined behavior in the standard.  If a simple rule can't be enforced (or the committee believes enforcing the rule is expensive), the rule stays in the standard and violations are declared to be undefined behavior.  [It is the programmer's responsibility to never trigger undefined behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html).  It is possible for compilers and related tools to enforce some of these rules some of the time.  It's even possible for some compilers or related tools to enforce some of these rules all of the time.  But, in general, you're on your own.

*Design and Evolution* even includes a discussion of your specific question.  After writing the compiler, Stroustrup didn't want to write a linker as well.  He came up with a simple way to rely on the system linker, but in the early days many linkers had severe restrictions on how long symbols could be.  He worked hard to convince the people who wrote the system linkers to change them enough to make them work with Cfront.  Eventually, he was successful.

Today, the linker generally comes with the compiler, but the standard committee still treats it as a separate tool, possibly outside the control of the people writing the compiler.  The one definition rule exists largely to make sure the compiler's output will be compatible with most standard linkers, but the committee doesn't require those linkers to be able to detect violations of the ODR.  Besides, it's possible for programs to be compiled and linked incrementally, so there is no guarantee that the linker will ever have enough information to detect a violation of the ODR.

It's worth noting that [many compilers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Template-Instantiation.html) will generate multiple symbols for `inline` functions and `template` functions, expecting the linker to throw out redundant definitions. So it's not necessarily an error for the linker to see multiple definitions. (As far as the ODR is concerned, those definitions must be identical so that the linker can throw away all but one.)

> What about it being in a library allows it to override the ODR?

I wouldn't say "override."  That sounds like the behavior is intentional.  I would say "violate without being detected."  The answer is simply "the standard committee doesn't expect the linker to always detect violations, and many linkers don't."  Avoiding ODR violations is your responsibility.  You aren't on your own, though:  namespaces exist partly to make this problem easier to solve.